# Delphi dll importing to C# - System.AccessViolationException DllImport

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, dllimport

Good day. I am struggling to get the function call to my Delphi to return data. I know the dll is working because if I use a show msg inside the dll it returns the right information.

I am thinking its to do with memory sizes that aren't the same. I also read a lot about prebuffering the memory, unfortunately, I don't have the know-who to implement it into my project

Exception details:
System.AccessViolationException
{"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

Delphi function:

```
function doStuff({var} c:string): pchar; stdcall;
```

C#

```
   [DllImport("Utili.dll",
          CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
          CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
   public static extern string doStuff(string a);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
          string q = "1234567890123456";
          string a =  doStuff(q);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: C# (or .NET) has no knowledge of Delphi's `string` type and doesn't know how to marshal it to C#'s (totally different) `string` datatype. If you want to export a function with a textual parameter from a DLL, use `PChar`, `PWideChar` or `PAnsiChar`, and *never* `string`. More here: http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html#types. Of course you will have to use the corresponding import (P-Invoke) clause in C#.

Comment: Is your dll using StdCall (windows) or C Language?

Comment: There are potentially many problems here. As a bare minimum show the Delphi implementation.

Comment: @jdweng Why ask that when it is clearly stated in the question?

Comment: It is not stated in the question, only in the code.  The code could be wrong.

Comment: The code is right. copied it and just changed the naming.

Comment: @jdweng The code **defines** the calling convention. You are familiar with Delphi syntax I presume?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The Delphi code sends back in PChar in you link you gave there isn't a corresponding variable type in c#?

Comment: @jdweng No, I got a DLL from a supplier that I have to use in my C# program

Comment: If you can't change the DLL then you won't be able to call it from C#. You'll need a Delphi adapter DLL. Even that might not be simple because of memory layout and management issues. We don't know how the return value allocation is handled. We don't know what PChar is. 8 bit or 16 bit. Nobody can give you a solution with so many unknowns. You'll need to talk to the vendor and work with them.

Comment: @Jaco: As I said, C# doesn't know anything about Delphi's `string` type. It knows how to handle C's `char *` or `wchar_t *` (Delphi equivalents `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar`, respectively). So only these types are allowed. If someone sent you a DLL exposing Delphi's `string`, they didn't think ahead, i.e. that languages other than Delphi -- of the same version -- might be using it. They should read my article to which I posted a link. Another example of a stupidly written DLL, in my opinion. You can probably do what David Heffernan says, i.e. use a wrapper DLL that converts `string` to `PChar`.

Comment: FWIW, does the DLL work with a simple Delphi program? If so, you at least know the type of string (`AnsiString` or `UnicodeString`) and can write an adapter/wrapper DLL. You should also know the bitness (32 bit, 64 bit) of the DLL.

Comment: I have been playing around with a wrapper class in Delphi. I think i am missing something. The wrapper class can showmsg() all the data I need but it gives me the same violation errors when I return data from the (Delphi) wrapper class

What is the purpose of the wrapper class? to do conversions of the data types? and am I am on the right track to write it in Delphi

Comment: I was under the understanding the return is pchar? or is the return not the problem but the fact that the parameter is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the supplier to fix their code.

If you have the Delphi code look into CoTaskMemAlloc